# Change value of const field at runtime

Tags: c#

This sound weird and one of the many things which should never be done, but In my application I am using a field which is const (say DefaultName) and this const field is used by many methods in different classes as default parameter.

```
 public const string DefaultName = "SomeName";
internal void ReadFromFile(string name = Const.DefaultName) { }
```

Based on new requirements this const field needs to change at runtime once so i marked it readonly and changed it in the constructor but then i am getting this error "Default parameter for value must be a compile time constant"

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Short answer, no. It's called `const` for a reason!

Comment: why not simply remove the name parameter from the ReadFromFile method and replace it with var name = Const.DefaultName; as the first line with the method?

Answer (score 3):

You can't get around this directly - the default value in the declaration must be const.

The usual way around this is to use some constant default which you can check for and then replace with the correct one:

```
internal void ReadFromFile(string name = null) 
{ 
    if (name == null)
        name = Const.DefaultName;

    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want people to be able to call ReadFromFile() with a null parameter, just overload it:

```
internal void ReadFromFile(string name) 
{ 
    if (name == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

    // ...
}

internal void ReadFromFile()
{
    ReadFromFile(Const.DefaultName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Default parameter values really do need to be a compile-time constants, because the compiler bakes the default value into the call site at compile-time.

That is, for the method call:

```
ReadFromFile();
```

The compiler literally turns this into the call:

```
ReadFromFile("SomeName");
```

You can see that in [SharpLab here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8BmAAiJoGEaBvCm9u2/FGgFRgDOAFwAUAShZsO0gEowAhhgBiUCAFslASwA2McQG4p7AL5GaZzQDshMKJfna6POYpXqtukfmIAGGvbUYGgBeRghLYQA6ABEYADN5AFdtIQA5eUCJM2ZzcmlTcgKKajpCMIihClY86RLICrpfGliE5LSMoNCAIgBldRh0wK79DgpjIA=).